# Qt convert to double without added precision

Tags: qt, double, rounding

There is a lot of questions on rounding that i have looked at but tey all involve rounding a number to its nearest whole, or to a certain number of points. What i want to do is simply convert a string to a double without any added digits on the right of the decimal point. Here is my code and result as of now:

Convert the string 0.78240 to a double, which should be 0.78240 but instead is 0.78239999999999998 when i look at it in the debugger.

The string value is a QString and is converted to a double simply using the toDouble() function.

I don't understand how or where these extra numbers are coming from, but any help on converting from QString to double directly would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The closest number to 0.78240 that can be exactly represented in IEEE 754 64-bit binary is 0.78239999999999998436805981327779591083526611328125. I am not sure what you want Qt to do other than pick the closest representable number to the decimal string.

Comment: So, is it impossible to represent the number 0.78240 exactly?? Excuse my ignorance on this topic... And if i go ahead and use its closest representation will all calculations based on that be in the same form??

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan : It is not a Qt issue, the displayed value is displayed by the debugger.

Comment: @Alan Correct. It happens because floating point is using a binary format, which can only represent a finite subset of the binary fractions. Just like there is no decimal fraction exactly equal to 1/3 there is no binary fraction exactly equal to 1/10.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan : That is the kernel of a worthwhile answer there - considering answering rather then commenting.

Comment: Thanks guys, will have to look into this some more!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extra digits are there because you are converting a decimal *real* number to *binary floating point*.

Unlike *real* numbers, floating-point representations have infinite resolution and finite range, and also *binary* floating-point values do not exactly coincide with all (or even most) *decimal* real values.

The simple fact is that *binary floating-point* cannot exactly represent 0.78240<sub>10</sub>, your debugger is showing you all the available digits after round-tripping the binary value back to decimal.

It is not necessarily a problem, because the error is infinitesimally small compared to the magnitude of the value, and in any event the original 0.78240 value is no doubt some approximation of a real-world value - they are both approximations, just binary or decimal approximations.

The issue is normally dealt with at presentation rather then representation.  For example, in this case, unlike your debugger which necessarily shows the full precision of the internal representation (you would not want it any other way in a debugger), the standard means of presenting such a value will limit itself to a small, or caller defined number of decimal places and this value presented to even 15 decimal places will be correctly presented as 0.782400000000000 (by default standard output methods will show just 0.7824).

Any `double` value *presented* at 15 *significant decimal figures* or fewer will display as expected, for a `float` this reduces to just 6 significant figures.  I imagine your debugger is displaying more digits that can accurately be presented in an IEEE 754 64-bit FP (double) value because internally the x86 FPU uses an 80bit representation.

You are quite literally sweating the small stuff.

One place where this difference in representation does matter is in financial applications.  For those, it is common to use *decimal floating point* and normally to many more significant figures than `double` can provide.  However decimal floating-point is not normally implemented in hardware, so is much slower.  Moreover decimal floating point is not directly supported in most programming languages, and requires library support.  C# is an example of a language with built-in support for decimal floating-point; its `decimal` type is good for 28 significant figures.